# Excel manipulation from C# - Set ActiveCell?

Tags: c#, excel, vb6, visual-studio-2010, interop

What is the C# equilivant to this VB6 to setting of the active cell?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("L1").Select
```

Comment: I assume you're going the COM route? If you're making Excel 2007 or later docs you should use the openXML route (.NET 3.0 / 3.5 required, although you can get far on your own using a zip-lib and vanilla XML manipulation in `System.Xml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a sample piece of code:

```
        Excel.Worksheet sht = (Excel.Worksheet)ActiveSheet;
        sht.Cells[3, 3] = "HELLO";
```

You can also capture ranges:

```
        Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)sht.Cells[3, 3];
```

I believe to you just the Select method as before to select a range, although I haven't tested this.

```
        rng.Select();
```

You can obviously streamline this and chain these statements together, with the right casting. I don't want to hazard a guess here as I've not got a VSTO project open in from of me.

**EDIT**

You should also be able to get a range from the sheet using `get_Range`:

```
        rng = sht.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);
```

VSTO tends to return Objects most of the time, necessitating casts, but `get_Range` is an exception. Someone might be able to correct me as I am not a big user of VSTO (still VBA die-hard when it comes to Excel).

Comment: Im so dense its unreal, I was trying the to to the rng.Select before actually assigning rng a cell! Thanks for making it obvious!

Comment: Small correction: get_Range takes 2 arguments (for cases where you want to select a group of cells), and it's one of these nice cases where it actually returns the right object type (Excel.Range) and not an object that requires casting... var cell = sheet.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);

Comment: @Mathias, thanks - corrected. I guess I was misremembering the situation with one input - where the second has to be Missing.